# Not-homeomorphic intervals.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Assume $[a,b)$ and $(a,b)$ are connected. Prove that $[a,b)$ and $(a,b)$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @Bhai Please do not vandalize posted questions. Rolled back.

Answer (score 5):

$[a,b)-\{a\}$ is connected but $(a,b)-$ a point is always disconnected.